# How to subset rows in a dataframe in R according to mean of variable?

Tags: r, subset, trim

I have a dataframe in R with 120 observations (participants). The mean age of all the sample is 51 years old (range 25-90). I would like to randomly select 60 of these observations to have a mean of 40. Is there a way of doing this? I would prefer to avoid manual trimming to avoid the issues that could come from that.

I appreciate any help that can be provided!

Comment: This is not an easy thing to do, if at all possible. Maybe you can get close to the mean you want using some kind of optimization. Please check this [thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94716/sampling-data-to-have-specific-mean-and-standard-deviation) asking for the same question and the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are constraining your sample to have a particular mean then it isn't a truly random sample. However, there are various ways to do this, none of which are easy. It depends on the distribution of ages in your sample, which of course I don't have.

Anyway, the following data frame will be somwhat similar to yours:

```
set.seed(772)
df <- data.frame(age = sample(25:90, 120, T), ID = factor(1:120))
```

We can see it has ages with the right range and about the right mean:

```
range(df$age)
#> [1] 25 90
mean(df$age)
#> [1] 51.23333
```

Now to get your sample ages to average 40, you will need to sample preferentially from the younger group. First we'll find the indices of the "old" and "young" participants:

```
young <- which(df$age <= 40)
old   <- which(df$age > 40)
```

Now we need to just try lots of samples (via a loop) until the mean is close to 40. To do this without completely truncating the older ages, we will take a 2:1 ratio of young to old participants for each sample. To do this, you'll need at least 40 participants under 40 in your data, which I'm guessing you do have.

```
seed <- 1

while(TRUE)
{
  set.seed(seed)
  young_indices <- young[sample(length(young), 40)]
  old_indices   <- old[sample(length(old), 20)]
  indices       <- c(young_indices, old_indices)

  if(abs(mean(df$age[indices]) - 40) < 0.25) break

  seed <- seed + 1
}

sample_df <- df[indices,]
```

Now `sample_df` will contain 60 unique participants whose average age is about 40;

```
nrow(sample_df)
#> [1] 60
mean(sample_df$age)
#> [1] 40.1
```